# Using the properties of Fourier Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I have calculated the following Fourier transform:

$F(\omega)=\frac{2}{\omega^2+1}$

for $f(t)= e^{-|t|}$

Now I need to find the Fourier transform for

$f_3(t)=cos(2t)e^{-{|t|}}$

Only using the properties of Fourier transform.

I am struggling to see which property is required here. Initially I tried the linearity property but I think this is wrong as $cos(2t)$ is not a constant. I tried to find the answer on maple and found it to be:  $\frac{2\omega^2+10}{\omega^4-6\omega^2+25}$

I can't see any property that would give me this.. I thought perhaps since they are two functions of $t$ I should use the Convolution theorem, but that would require me to know the Fourier transform of $cos(2t)$ which is undefined, from what Maple tells me.

I'm out of ideas, I feel as though I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us observe that
$$ \cos 2t= \frac 1 2 \left( e^{2it} + e^{-2it} \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{i\omega t}\left( \pi \delta(\omega - 2)+\pi\delta(\omega+ 2)\right),$$
where $\delta(\omega)$ denotes the Dirac delta function.

From this, it is clear that the Fourier transform of $\cos 2t$ is $\pi \delta(\omega - 2)+\pi\delta(\omega+ 2)$.

Now you can apply the convolution theorem.

---

Alternative approach, without using convolutions or the delta function:

The Fourier transform of $\cos 2t f(t)$ is
\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{-i\omega t}\cos 2tf(t)  & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt \ e^{-i\omega t}\times \tfrac 1 2 \left( e^{2it} + e^{-2it}\right) f(t) \\ & =  \tfrac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{-i(\omega - 2) t}f(t) + \tfrac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{-i(\omega + 2) t}f(t) \\ & = \tfrac 1 2 \widetilde f(\omega - 2) + \tfrac 1 2 \widetilde f(\omega + 2). \end{align*}

Comment: P.S. Depending on your conventions, you may need to insert factors of $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: We have never been taught the Dirac delta function, so I'm wondering if there is perhaps a different way? Is it possible to write $cos(2t)$ in the way that you have and then separate the equation using linearity and calculate each side using the frequency shift property?

Comment: @N.K. I've added an alternative approach - see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! My question asks for a method without evaluating any integrals however so I guess there is a possible 3rd method I need to find

Comment: @N.K. Actually my method doesn't REALLY involve evaluating any integrals. I only really used the standard fact that the Fourier transform of $e^{ia x} f(x)$ is $\tilde f(\omega - a)$.